# Problems with setting the path for Zend framework, needed for Youtube API

Tags: zend-framework, installation

I copied & pasted this text here. It seems the editor seems to format some parts randomly. ;)

I downloaded ZendGdata 1.9.6, extracted it & uploaded it to my site's
root folder ..., which I need for use with Youtube API to get videos onto my site.
I must say I’m new to all this, and so I would appreciate taking this into account.

The library folder is at /ZendGdata/library.

The problem I'm having is Step. 3 when I follow instructions 
(http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/gdata/articles/php_client_lib.html#gdata-installation)

for setting it up for that purpose.

1. Download the Google Data Client Library files.
2. Decompress the downloaded files. Four sub-directories should be
   created:

   - demos — Sample applications
   - documentation — Documentation for the client library files
   - library — The actual client library source files.
   - tests — Unit-test files for automated testing.
3. Add the location of the library folder to your PHP path (see the next  section)

One of the suggested locations to add the path, apart from the .htaccess file is in php.ini.
My site is on shared hosting. I have no access to the main php.ini file, but I’m allow to create one if I need one. For Drupal CMS, for some functions, it suffices placing one in the root folder.

I added this line:

```
include_path=".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/habaris6/
public_html/site.root.folder/ZendGdata/library";
```

When I however go to mysite.com/ZendGdata/demos/Zend/Gdata/InstallationChecker.php to test the set up, like is mentioned in the 
documentation on Youtube, I get the error:

```
PHP Extension ErrorsTested No errors found

Zend Framework Installation Errors: Tested 0

Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using 'use_include_path' = true. 
Make sure you include Zend Framework in your include_path which currently 
contains: .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php

SSL Capabilities Errors: Not tested 

YouTube API Connectivity Errors: Not tested
```

So my question is: Is that the correct way to “Add the location of the library folder to your PHP path” ?
I’m a bit mixed up.

Someone was saying the php.ini file is only active in the folder where it is located. If that is the case, which of the ZendGdata folders should have it?
As I said, my purpose is to have a the Zend framework properly set up to allow using Youtube API, something I also yet have to learn to do.

In Youtube API Google group, I was referred here. The documentation coming with the downloaded file & at zend.com pre-supposes, one knows much more than some beginners like me.

Another person said I try placing this

```
$clientLibraryPath = '/home/habaris6/public_html/site.root.folder/ZendGdata/library';
$oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $clientLibraryPath);
```

in mysite.com/ZendGdata/demos/Zend/Gdata/InstallationChecker.php

Whereas everything I had tried before failed, except fot the first test, when I placed the above snippet in the installation checker, I got positive tests for everything:

```
Ran PHP Installation Checker on 2009-12-09T21:16:08+00:00

PHP Extension ErrorsTested: No errors found 

Zend Framework Installation Errors Tested No errors found 

SSL Capabilities ErrorsTested No errors found 

YouTube API Connectivity ErrorsTested No errors found
```

Does it mean if I place that snippet in install checker, all scripts needing the library can access it?

If not, please let me know what exactly to place in the self-made php.ini & in which folder(s) it should be.
Should that not work, and I were to use .htaccess files, what exactly, based on the folders mentioned above should be the content & exactly which folders should they be in? I read that the .htaccess files should be placed in each folder. Does it really mean I should place one in each of the ZendGdata folders? 
I would be grateful for any guidance enabling me to finally start, after failing to sufficient get responses elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to put all the ZendGdata code under your website document root.  In fact, as a rule I *don't* put PHP class libraries in a location that can be accessed directly by web requests, because if there's any way to do mischief by invoking the class files directly, then anyone can do it.

Instead, put libraries outside your document root and then reference them from scripts that are run directly.  For example, you could create a directory `phplib` as a sister to your `public_html` directory.  Then upload the ZendGdata bundle under that `phplib` directory.

You can set your PHP include path in a .htaccess file.  You *don't* need to create a .htaccess file in every directory, because the directives in any .htaccess file apply to all files and directories under the directory where the .htaccess resides.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html for more information.

So I would recommend creating a .htaccess file at /home/habaris6/public_html/site.root.folder containing the following directives:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value include_path ".:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/habaris6/phplib/ZendGdata/library"
</IfModule>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php for more info on this.

Note that this assumes your webhosting company allows you to use .htaccess files, and that they allow you to use the `php_value` directive in .htaccess files.  Enabling these options is an Apache configuration and they could have their own policies against that for reasons of performance or security.  You should contact them for this answer; no one on the internet can answer questions about your hosting provider's policies.

If you choose to use the `set_include_path()` PHP function to append a directory to your runtime include path, you need to do this in each file that serves as a landing point for a web request.  That is, if you permit a request to be made directly to `foo.php` then you need to add the code to `foo.php`.  Any files or classes subsequently included by `foo.php` use the include path you defined.

Note also that whatever method you use to define the include path, it has to take effect *before* your script tries to load any PHP class files via the include path.  The .htaccess method should accomplish this, and if you use the code method you just have to put the code high enough in your PHP script.

I don't use the method of creating a custom `php.ini` file under each directory within your site document tree.  That's a new feature of PHP 5.3.0, not supported by earlier versions of PHP.  If you're using Apache you should just use .htaccess for the same effect.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed response.
I followed your advice & transferred the library to /phplib/ 
For some reason, the .htaccess method did not work, probably I'm not allowed to create one. I'm yet to find that out. I did however put that piece of code in the custom php.ini file & this time the install checker reported no errors & all clear. I however needed set_include_path() in /ZendGdata/demos/Zend/Gdata/YouTubeVideoApp/operations.php to make /ZendGdata/demos/Zend/Gdata/YouTubeVideoApp/ work. Now trying to understand how to move on. Many thanks & I know where 2 turn if I get stuck.:)