# zend installation

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

Running on W7, php5.3.5.
I have downloaded and installed Zend framework files. Now I'm trying to run the PHP Installation cheker [recommended here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib?hl=es) but it return an eror:

```
Ran PHP Installation Checker on 2012-08-27T13:06:37+00:00
PHP Extension Errors          Tested
No errors found
Zend Framework Installation   Tested
Errors
0                             Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php
                              using 'use_include_path' = true.
                              Make sure you include Zend Framework in your
                              include_path which currently contains:
                              .;C:\php\pear
SSL Capabilities Errors       Not tested
YouTube API Connectivity      Not tested
Errors
```

Here are similar question to mine [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762866/youtube-api-strange-issue-with-zendgdata) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877167/problems-with-setting-the-path-for-zend-framework-needed-for-youtube-api)

Already tried [this solution](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=5011) and other similar ones but the error keeps appearing.

**Edit 01:**
Using [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) and [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) I'm trying to include the path but is not working. When I call a `get_include_path()` it returns again the `.;C:\php\pear`.

Here is the php to add the path:

```
<?php
$path = '.C:\php\zend';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
?>
```

**Edit 02:**
Found `php.ini`, edited and added: `include_path = ".;c:\php\pear;.;c:\php\lib\Zend"` according to [this link on the Google developers page](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib?hl=es#appendix_phpini). The errors still appears, but now adding `.;c:\php\lib\Zend` to the path.

Comment: `Make sure you include Zend Framework in your include_path` and the problem is?

Comment: edited my question to clarify...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit the `php.ini` like mentioned in "[Description of core php.ini directives](http://php.net/core.php#ini.include-path)".

```
include_path=".:/php/includes"
```

Remember, that in most cases the different sapis use different `php.ini` files. On CLI use `php --ini` to find the appropiate one.

Comment: Found that file. Edited and added: `include_path = ".;c:\php\pear;.;c:\php\lib\Zend"` according to [this link on the Google developers page](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib?hl=es#appendix_phpini). The errors still appears, but now adding `.;c:\php\lib\Zend` to the path. Editing my question again.

Comment: What is _exactly_ in `c:\php\lib\Zend`? I ask, because the include path must point to the library folder and not the whole package. I guess it is `c:\php\lib\Zend\library` or something like that.

Comment: Hmmm...now you got me...I saw everywhere the `library` and I thought it was refering to the full folder of Zend framework. Then what should I write instead of `library`? Just checked what I downloaded from [here](http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata/) and I see there is a `library` folder. Modified the path and name of folder to point to this one, same result.

Comment: @Yaroslav Oh .... OK, you downloaded the only GData-API ;) To download the Zend Framework try http://framework.zend.com/download/latest ("1.11.13 full"). It contains the GData-API too. Just ignore, what you don't want to use, but as far as I remember the separate GData-API-package really only contains this

Comment: Downloading...but I already have a huge Zend folder on my Magento installation folder, shouldn't that cover my needs?

Comment: Should do it. But I guess this is not in `c:\php\lib\Zend`? To sum it up: There must be an unpackaed Zend Framework package somewhere and one entry of the include-path must point to the `Zend/library/`-folder

Comment: Your last suggestion did the work. Nevertheless I should change the path as I'm using an absolute path now `include_path = "C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\library"` and i guess I should be using a relative one. Any recommendation?

Comment: The unpacked ZF package of Magento resides in `lib/Zend`, relative to the Magento root folder. Magentos bootstrapping OOB calls PHP `set_include_path()` to add the `lib` folder (amongst others) to the include path and initializes an autoloader. See the top of [`app/Mage.php`](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/Mage.php).